# Why is $\{x:f(x)\ge a\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\{x: f(x)\gt a-\frac{1}{n}\}$ and $\{x: f(x)\gt a\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{x: f(x)\ge a+\frac{1}{n}\}$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

It is known from measure theory that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is measurable.
2. The set $\{x : f(x) \ge a\}$ is measurable.
3. The set $\{x : f(x) \gt a\}$ is measurable.

In virtually all textbooks, for the proof of the above is as follows:

$2 \rightarrow 3$: $\{x : f(x) \ge a\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x: f(x) \gt a - \frac{1}{n}\}$

$3 \rightarrow 2$: $\{x : f(x) \gt a\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x: f(x) \ge a + \frac{1}{n}\}$

Can someone clarify as to why those equalities above hold? I'm having difficult picturing it. For instance, why is:

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x: f(x) \ge a + \tfrac{1}{n}\} = \{x : f(x) \ge a + 1\} \cup\cdots \cup \{x: f(x) \ge a\}$$ equal to: $\{x: f(x) \gt a\}$ and NOT: $\{x: f(x) \ge a\}$?

Comment: Be careful with your quantifiers. Saying that "*for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, statement $P$ and statement $Q(a)$ are equivalent*", is **not** the same thing as "*statement $P$ is equivalent to statement $Q(a)$ being true for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $x_0$ is a point at which $f(x)=a$. For which $n$ do you think  $x_0$ is going to be in the set
$$\{x:f(x)\geq a+\tfrac{1}{n}\} \quad ?$$
If it is not in any such set, how will it be in
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{x:f(x)\geq a+\tfrac{1}{n}\}\quad ?$$

---

The fact that the question is phrased in terms of functions is not important; it is more generally true that, for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$a\geq b\iff a>b-\tfrac{1}{n}\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N}$$
and 
$$a>b\iff \text{ there is some }n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }a\geq b+\tfrac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Why doesn't $n = \infty$ work here?

Comment: $\infty$ is not a natural number. The notation $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$ means the same thing as
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$$

Comment: What Zev said.  The notation $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty$ may be confusing... in means union over all $n$ in $\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ and that set does not include $\infty$.

Comment: So is what I did here not correct either? $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x: f(x) \ge a + \tfrac{1}{n}\} = \{x : f(x) \ge a + 1\} \cup\cdots \cup \{x: f(x) \ge a\}$$

Comment: @Hello: That's right, that equation is not correct. Of course, the ellipsis is somewhat vague in itself, but the "correct" thing to write is just
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x: f(x) \ge a + \tfrac{1}{n}\} = \{x : f(x) \ge a + 1\} \cup\{x : f(x) \ge a + \tfrac{1}{2}\}\cup \cdots $$

Comment: Ah thank you very much. Set theory is annoying. :(

Comment: @Hello: Just takes some getting used to - everyone usually starts out with many incorrect intuitions about infinity. Studying math helps you figure out what's really true!